# How to bind NSArrayController to NSTableView programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, data-binding, nstableview

I have constructed a window with a single view-based NSTableView, programmatically (code-only, without XIB) following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599747/programmatically-creating-an-nstableview-trouble-getting-the-nsheaderview-to-sh), which is backed by an *Array* in **swift**.
I instead want to back it by an **NSArrayController** so had it simply by:

```
var controller = NSArrayController()
```

and modify its contents, when needed, using one of its proper methods:

```
controller.addObject(item)
controller.removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex(index)
controller.insertObject(item, atArrangedObjectIndex: atIndex)
```

and bound it with:

```
tableView.bind(NSContentBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", options: nil)
tableView.bind(NSSelectionIndexesBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath:"selectionIndexes", options: nil)
tableView.bind(NSSortDescriptorsBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath: "sortDescriptors", options: nil)
```

Cell views are created in the delegate with:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        // ... erased code for finding cellIdentifier and text.. 
        view = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, owner: nil) as? PLTextCellView
        if view == nil {
            print("new view for text: "+text)            
            view = NSTextField()
            view!.identifier = cellIdentifier
        }
        view!.stringValue = text        
        return view
}
```

Add/remove and number of items work ok but object id's are displayed, in the cells, between '<' and '>', instead of the values I assign as *text*. This was working fine before the *NSArrayController*. What do I need to do?

Notes: 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583638/create-view-based-nstableview-programmatically-using-bindings-in-swift) question gives an -incomplete- answer which give `An instance of ...item... was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.` error.
I also did bind my table according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804346/3648895) answer which only states a necessity to bind the cells also, manually. I am asking how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create view based NSTableView programmatically using Bindings in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583638/create-view-based-nstableview-programmatically-using-bindings-in-swift)

Comment: @Willeke : It is not; edited and clarified accordingly, see the notes.

Comment: `NSTableCellView` and `viewForTableColumn` are used by view based tableviews. Subclasses of `NSCell` and `dataCellForTableColumn` are used by cell based tableviews.

Comment: "Note that a cell view’s identifier must be the same as its table column’s identifier for bindings to work."

Comment: @Willeke : Had thought of it once and had already done, without any effect...